# Tomcat doesn't watches .html files

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, http-status-code-404, tomcat10

I created Spring MVC project, made two simple controllers and views, that they are returning. But when I go to required path (ex.: `localhost:8080/otters`), I see 404 error (image below)

**GitHub**: https://github.com/nikita-popov-java/SpringMVCTemplate

[image: image below]

I tryed clean|install maven, restart server\computer\reinstall IDE, changed java\tomcat versions, nothing was worked =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is ridiculously simple. All problems there was because I extended my SpringConfig class from `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` instead of `WebMvcConfigurer`